# HTML text color in disabled text box

Tags: html, textbox

I have a `text box` in html, I have set the `text box` to `disabled`,

```
<input type="text" style="background-color:transparent; text-align:center" disabled="disabled" />
```

So the text color in this `text box` is gray, how can I change it to any color I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`color:xxx` and provide some value for the textbox

```
<input type="text" style="background-color:transparent; color:red; 
text-align:center" disabled="disabled" value="some values"/>
```

work for chrome, firefox, except internet explorer

Answer (score 3):

You can try with [css selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) as shown below but as "Sarfarz" mentioned browsers might or might not honor this. But you can test

```
input[disabled='disabled'] 
{
  ...styles
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.

```
input:disabled {
  background: #000;
}
```